# PHP Replace URL Except Images

Tags: php

Need suggestion about my Replace URL function.

That function is worked but now facing problem when in the text contain images. The image not show.

Here is my function

```
function tolink( $text = null )
{
$regex = '/((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/';
return preg_replace_callback( $regex, function( $m )
{
    $link = $name = $m[0];
    if(empty($m[1]))
    {
        $link = "http://".$link;
    }
    return '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.$name.'</a>';
}, $text );
}
echo tolink("google.com <img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/440636713354817536/I_Z3SDmE_reasonably_small.png'/>");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't run the replace on HTML nodes, only their text content.

Comment: Any example of that?

Comment: Pick your preferred DOM parser, iterate over the nodes and do your replace on the text. I don't think an example will make that much easier.

Comment: Could skip tags by putting `<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)` before the regex: `'/<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!["\'])((http`... if attributes won't contain `<>` ([see test](https://regex101.com/r/uE7hS4/1)) but it's a bad idea to use regex here, your pattern also matches something like `1.1` eg `echo tolink("1.1 things to think about");` => `<a href="http://1.1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">1.1</a> things to think about`

Comment: Hi @Jonny5, I tried and now worked as I want. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You're welcome HiDayurieDave :]